# JavaScript Decrementing Alphabet Function

Tags: javascript

New to the JavaScript language and need help creating a function which generates the following display.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

.... and so on, all the way down to

```
                       xyz
                        yz
                         z
```

I am not asking for handouts, just a little kickstart for a beginner to get started! Links, hints, tips, anything helps! Thanks!

Comment: you should show what you've tried, and we can help you from there.

Comment: just check my code demo and let me know is it you want :)

Comment: Super helpful responses, thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

Arrays and loops are powerful when combined.

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
console.log(alphabet.join(''));

while (alphabet.​length > 0) {
    alphabet.shift();
    console.log(alphabet.join(''));
}​​​
```

**Edit:**
If you really need your decremented alphabet to be left-padded, you can use this:

```
var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var letters = alphabet.split('');
var addPadding = (function (minLength) {
    return function (shortString) {
        if (shortString.length < minLength) {
            return new Array(
                minLength - shortString.length + 1
            ).join(' ') + shortString;
        }
    };
}(alphabet.length));

console.log(alphabet);
while (letters.length > 0) {
    letters.shift();
    console.log(addPadding(letters.join('')));
}
```

**Edit:**
Here is a *much* simpler answer:

```
function decrementingAlphabet () {
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

    function iterate(spaces, letters) {
        if (letters.length > 0) {
            console.log(spaces + letters);
            iterate(spaces + ' ', letters.substring(1));
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    iterate('', alphabet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example.

```
var str = '';
for (var s=0; s < 26; ++s) {
    str = '';
    for (var i=0; i < 26 - s; ++i) {
        str += String.fromCharCode(97+s+i);
    }
    document.write(str + "<br/>");
}
```

​
See http://jsfiddle.net/G5Gds

Answer (score 0):

In character codes, small alphabets lie from 97 onwards(97 for a). You need to use 2 for loops to print such series.

Here is your [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/EHtEz/2/):

```
var display='';
for(var i=97;i<123;i++){
    var s='';
    for(var j=i;j<123;j++){
        s+= String.fromCharCode( j );       
    }           
    display+=s;
} 
alert(display);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, maybe this will help put you on the right track?

```
var str = '';

// Find out what 'a' is in ASCII
var baseLetterCode = 'a'.charCodeAt(0);

// Loop once for each letter
for (var i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
    // Append to string
    str += String.fromCharCode(baseLetterCode + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
  var theENalphabet = [];
  for (var charNow = "a".charCodeAt(0); charNow <= "z".charCodeAt(0); charNow += 1) {
       theENalphabet.push(String.fromCharCode(charNow));
  }
  var isNow = 0;
  function decrAlph(startAt) {
     var alphString = "";
     for (var i = startAt; i < theENalphabet.length; i += 1) {
         alphString += theENalphabet[i];
     }
     console.log(alphString);
     isNow++;
     while (isNow < theENalphabet.length) {
         decrAlph(startAt + 1);
     }
  };
  decrAlph(0);
})();
```

The charCode getting could be abstracted into a function:

```
var getCharCode = function(el){
    return String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(el, 0);
};
getCharCode("a"); // returns 97..
```